# Ist "Mein Deutsch geht besser als früher" korrekt?

Tags: phrase

Kann man so sagen:

> Mein Deutsch geht besser als früher.

Oder nur:

> Ich kann Deutsch jetzt besser als früher!

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is wrong. The verb *gehen* doesn't work here, because the construction is "to be able to do something" (*etwas können*). That is why you would say "*Deutsch können*".

Additionally, I would put the time at the beginning of the sentence, that emphasizes that you are a better speaker now: *Jetzt kann ich Deutsch besser als früher!*

Another option would be pick it up as a question if somebody asks for your progress of learning several languages.

*Deutsch? Kann ich jetzt besser! (als Französisch).*

Comment: Simple, but also perfectly fine: *Mein Deutsch `ist` besser als früher.* (*sein* - to be / is)